# Having trouble using pyo in kivy

Tags: python, import, module, kivy, pyo

I'm not sure if anyone has any experience with this, but I'm trying to write a program using kivy and pyo(Python digital signal processing module).
This is what the beginning of my code looks like:

```
from pyo import *  
import time, kivy  
kivy.require('1.8.0')
```

But every time I run the code(using sendTo), it says "there is no module named pyo".
Is there anyway to use modules outside of kivy and Python library?
(Sorry if my question is unclear)

Comment: Please provide a complete code example which produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pip install pyo with the Python provided by the Kivy for Windows bundle:

1. Start kivy.bat
2. pip install pyo